# Composition series after quotient is still composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$\{1\} =G_n\lhd G_{n-1}\lhd \cdots \lhd G_{1} \lhd G_{0} = G$ be the composition series of G and $K\lhd G$ Then after we eliminate equalities. Show that $\{1\} \lhd KG_n/K \lhd KG_{n-1}/K \lhd \cdots \lhd KG_1/K \lhd KG_0/K = G/K$ is a composition series of G/K

I want to prove it by contradiction. WLOG, 
$$(KG_0/K)/(KG_1/K)$$ is not simple. Then exists proper Q
$$Q \lhd (KG_0/K)/(KG_1/K)$$ By 3rd isomorphism thm, we have 
$$\dot Q \lhd KG_0/KG_1$$ and,
$$KG_1 \lhd \ddot Q \lhd KG_0 \ \ \ and\ \ \  \ddot Q/KG_1 \cong  \dot Q$$ 
Then, I want to proper
$$\ \dddot Q\ne G_1 or\ G_0\ s.t.\ G_1 \lhd \dddot Q \lhd G_0$$
Then we get contradiction.
But I have no idea how to accomplish last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** There is a canonical map $ \phi : G_0 \to KG_0 / KG_1 $, which is obviously surjective. Show that $ G_1 \subset \ker \phi $, so that the map descends to the quotient. What can you say about the homomorphic image of a simple group?

Comment: Are you saying that $G_0 /  G_1$ is abelian group? Why? I know that after quotient are simple group, does that implies abelian?

Comment: By factor theorem, there is a group homo from $\varphi :G_0/G_1 \rightarrow KG_0/KG_1$ and is onto since $\phi$ is onto. We already have $\dot Q$ is proper normal subgroup of $KG_0/KG_1$ and let $N = \varphi^{-1} (\dot Q)$ . $N \ne \{1\} or\ G_0/G_1$ and it is normal since $\forall a,b \in N \varphi(a)\varphi(b)\varphi(b)^{-1}\in \dot Q \Rightarrow \varphi(aba^{-1})\in\dot Q \Rightarrow aba^{-1} \in N$. Now we get proper normal that $N \lhd G_0/G_1$, and contradiction to $G_0/G_1$ is simple. Is  my argument right?

Comment: My bad - what can you say about the homomorphic image of a simple group, then? Your argument is needlessly complicated.

Comment: Is that image of simple group is either 1-1 or identity? Therefore,  $\phi:\ G_0/G_1→KG_0/KG_1$ is 1-1 and onto homo. We have $KG_0/KG_1$ is simple iff $G_0/G_1$ is simple.

Comment: Sorry for too dumb question, first. Why $\varphi$ is onto?